# Can I target multiple divs with one nth-child() selector?

Tags: css

Say I have a parent div with three child divs inside and I want to give each child a different background colour, can this be done with only one nth-child selector - my parent div has a class of "parent" and the three children have classes of "child1", "child2", "child3".

Thanks.

Comment: That's what classes are for.

Comment: if u want to give them different bg, u have to call them individually

Comment: How 1 selector can define 3 different colors?

Comment: 3 different colours with one selector? your question doesn't make sense

Comment: Yes. if 1 selector can target all three and I can assign them all different background colours in one target.

Comment: Well that's not possible to assign three different colours with the same selector

Comment: Sorry but do you know how css works? Let's say you can catch them all with one selector, how the style itself will look?

Comment: Something like this: :nth-child(?){ background:red;background:blue;background:yellow}

Comment: hahaha, I think you need to learn more about css the above will only show a yellow background - the other 2 will be overridden.  Do some basic tutorials and you will soon learn this

Comment: @MarkSLCarlyon css doesn't work that's way. Simple is that.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was some shorthand for achieving this, rather than writing out three separate targets.

Comment: @Mark S L Carlyon: No, there isn't. Even in your example, you had to write out three separate background declarations. Similarly you'll need to target each element separately, since you're looking to style separate elements.

Comment: Your question is simple, the answer is simple. No. You can use [sass](https://sass-lang.com/), it will give you some shorthand in the dev process.

Comment: Thanks Mosh Feu. At least now I can come at this the RIGHT way.

Comment: @MarkSLCarlyon see my explain in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Yoy can't set 3 `background-color` in one selector (the 2 override by last defenition) as in image

[image] 
I recommand you learn about `selector` in css:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp 
**and more learn here**(thanks to @Mosh Feu):https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors 
**and:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors 
**SO you have to do it as below:**

```css
.parent .child1{
background-color:red;
}
.parent .child2{
background-color:orange;
}
.parent .child3{
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child1">one </div>
 <div class="child2">tow </div>
 <div class="child3">three </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MoshFeu I was busy to set snippet and i didnt see

Comment: I will take it :) also you can add to your answer more specific links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this with just one rule and just one selector.

In CSS, every rule applies a specific set of styles to all the elements that match its selector(s). This is a fundamental aspect of how CSS works. You can't have different declarations in a single rule apply selectively to specific elements — they will all just get overridden, leaving you with just one winning declaration that gets applied to all the elements that are matched. This is true even if you have multiple selectors in the same rule, and even if you use `:nth-child()` instead of class selectors.

For example,

```
.child1, .child2, .child3 {
  background-color: red;
  background-color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

is treated as

```
.child1, .child2, .child3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

which applies a yellow background to all three children, both **despite** *and* **because of** the fact that all three children are listed. The same holds true with `.parent > :nth-child(1), .parent > :nth-child(2), .parent > :nth-child(3)` as the selector.

Therefore, if you want to style three elements differently, you will need three rules, one for each element:

```
.child1 {
   background-color: red;
}

.child2 {
   background-color: blue;
}

.child3 {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

Again, this is true regardless of what selector you use to actually reach each child element. The point is that each set of style declarations (`property: value` pairs) needs to appear in its own set of `selector {}` rules.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use nth selector if your child elements use different classes? Nth-selector should be used for elements that haven't got class selector or where the content is dynamic. In this particular case you don't need nth selector, just use

```css
.parent .child1 {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.parent .child2 {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">child1</div>
  <div class="child2">child2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of this.

Comment: So if I am understanding you correctly, you give the parent a class name but not the children, then you target the parent and children inside. I've automatically been giving them their own classes to target them individually, as I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: @Mark S L Carlyon: Yes, that's what :nth-child() is for. That being said, the point remains that you won't be able to apply different styles to each element with just one rule, since every rule always applies exactly one set of styles to all the elements that match its selector.

Comment: You can read more about child selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this.

Comment: @MarkSLCarlyon If any of the answers is the one, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it, so it will may help to other people.